# insert mysql content into html?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, mysql, sql

Hi im trying to figure out a way to write mysql content to html code:

I have an area on my asp page named `<div id="test1"></div>` (this area is static)

I want to take content from my table and place code inside this div under a different div name (div id=sqlcontent)

so it would look like this:

```
<div id="test1">
        <div id="mysqlcontent">something the user would write which is stored in my db</div>
</div>
```

is there a way like this:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl; 

public partial class UserProfileWall : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        //Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(theUserId);

        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=x; Password=x;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT WallPosting.Wallpostings FROM WallPosting LEFT JOIN WallPosting ON User.UserID = WallPosting.UserID WHERE User.UserID=" + theUserId + "", cn))
            //{

            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", theUserId);


            using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder("<div id=mysqlcontent>");
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    divHtml.Append(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
                }

                divHtml.Append("</div>");
                test1.innerHtml = divHtml.ToString();
// error on this line innerHtml does not contain a definition for'innerHtml'?
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure its possible with C# in asp to do that so I have attempted below a way via jquery incase? But im unsure how to write in j?

```
$(function () {

    $(page load).**unsure what goes here**(function () {
        var x = $(retrieve some data from mysql table unsure if jquery can do this).val();
        var newdiv = $("<div></div>").html(x).attr('id', 'mysqlcontent');
        $('#test1').append(newdiv);
    });
});
```

ASP html:

```
</script>
<p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" name="TextBox1" runat="server" Rows="3" 
        Height="47px" Width="638px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Post Message" Width="98px" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </p>
<p>
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" name="Table1" runat="server" Width="488px"></asp:Table>
</p>

<div id="test1" runat="server" />

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic C# implementation, if you tag the test1 div with `runat="server"` ...

```
<div id="test1" runat="server" />
```

... then you can reference it in your code behind ...

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl test1;
```

... and can build up the content using the DataReader before setting the content

```
// prepare DataReader
var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder("<div id=mysqlcontent>")
while (reader.Read()) {
   divHtml.Append("something built from your database text");
}
divHtml.Append("</div>")
test1.InnerHtml = divHtml.ToString();
```

Comment: `<div id="test1" runat="server" /></div>` if I do this I get the end tag has no start tag?

Comment: `<div id="test1" runat="server" />` doesn't require the close tag, its the equivalent of `<div id="test1" runat="server"></div>` but uses less chars (you'll need to play spot the difference).

Comment: do I put my sql statement under the protected global unsure where that goes?

Comment: my sql statement is kept in the pageload atm

Comment: Yes, Page_Load is fine. The declaration of the `HtmlGenericControl` depends on the version of C# you're using. For later versions, it will be in the `partial class` in the page's `designer.cs` file.

Comment: (using vs2010) Ive edited my post but I get an error for innerHtml says theres no definition for it?

Comment: Can you post your declaration for test1?

Comment: Sorry, the property is `InnerHtml` not `innerHtml`

Comment: ahhh haha my bad thanks that was it! Ok this looks good just need to check my sql syntax then give it a wurl but thank you very much this has gave me a headache, I have an insert statment bound to a button (causes postback) so when I click the button and add to the database im hoping this should output it back to the page.

Comment: Good luck. Depending on your reasons for developing and the level you want to get to, you could consider moving your SQL out of the code-behind. Larger applications benefit from proper partitioning of "responsibilities": e.g. UI preparation, transfer from/to the database, and the application of business logic can be done by specialised classes (with the purpose of easing maintenance, avoiding spaghetti-like designs). There's material on the web that describes patterns like MVC. At this point, perhaps just an appreciation that there are better, more complicated, ways is enough! :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can add literal control inside div.

```
<div id="test1">
<div id="mysqlcontent">
<asp:literal id="literal1" runat="server"></asp:literal>
</div>
</div>
```

After this you can apply any data (including html tags) you want like this

```
 literal1.Text="something";
 literal1.Text+="More data";
```

Comment: haha thats also clever, but the div id="mysqlcontent" is dynmaically assgined to each comment held withint my database (there would be multiple div = mysqlcontents) under div = test1 see above for a genious approach to it

Comment: So simply delete <div id="mysqlcontent"> .Generate that div before you loop throgh DB content.Something like this. StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();   str.append("<div id="mysqlcontents">); append more data inside  while (reader.Read()). finally close div str.append("</div>") and pass str to literal, literal1.text=str.toString();

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mysqlcontent").html("sqlthere")
```

**EDIT**

To achieve your goal you have to know how ajax works but also -what is ajax?-.

I'm not going to write down a whole course with what I know, but just some straight information. Ajax is a mechanism that allows you to do asynchronous calls. Exemple, your client visits your website, the main page is loaded. And people keep posting for example news, you don't want the user to be forced to refresh for him getting the new news, you just want to keep the main page the way it is, and just query the server and ask it if it's got some news for us.

Neither Javascript nor JQuery can talk to MySQL, or any other RDBM. You have to create a file let's say: getComments.asp

All this file does is query the mysql database and return back the results in any format you'd like (plain text, html, xml, json, ...etc).

Then in the client side you do something like:

1- In case your getComments.asp returns your comments within HTML for example it might return:

```
  <div class="coment">I am a good comment</div>
  <div class="coment">I am a short</div>
  <div class="coment">I am a looooooooooooooooooong</div>
```

Then, in jquery you do:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getComments.asp',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#myCommentsDiv').html(data);
  }
});
```

2- Json: Asp returns comments in json (see http://www.google.be/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+json) and in your code you do:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getComments.asp',
      DataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
            var comments = eval('(' + data + ')');
            for (comm in comments){
                $('#commentsDiv').prepend("<div class='comment'>" + comm + "</div>");
            }

  }
});
```

For more information on jquery/ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You've set jquery in the tags, I assumed you're performing this task through Ajax. In your success function, you set your content that way. Unless I haven't understood your question :)

Comment: yeah I have set jquery because everyone keeps saying its the only way, im very novice at it tho, I know where to place it understand what its doing but cant write it yet.

Comment: Well, we don't know what code you do have already, show some.

Comment: ive re edited what or how I would try achieve it via jquery maybe you could help me achieve my goal, sorry for it looking lame just dont know how jquery calls mysql? or does it? or can it?

Comment: My answer has been updated. Ask if you get further wonders ;)

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are several ways and the most easiest way is to put the runat="server" in the div mysqlcontent then @ the time of postback ur able to access this div.

The Other way is using ajax method or using jQuery.

Comment: I cant put runat server in the mysqlcontent because I have to create that for each of the comments in my database on page load, only the test1 div is static so I have to find a way of taking generic content from my database wrap it in my div id="sqlcontent" then place it in the div id=test1